# Пропадает звук  при проигрывании в интернете видиороликов в Ubunte 10.04

Tags: flash

Пропадает звук  при проигрывании видиороликов в Ubunte 10.04. Видеоролики проигрываются в хроме и в лисе. Эффект одинаковый. После начала проигрывания проходит от 10 сек. до 2-х мин. и звук пропадает. После обновления страницы и начала проигрывания с того момента, где пропал звук, иногда доигрывает до конца, но такое бывает редко. Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

В линуксе несколько видов вывода звука, есть ALSA, PulseAudio и еще несколько. Бывает такое, что скайп во время получения сообщения или звонка отключает в других приложениях звук и восстановить обратно звук надо перезапуском приложений. Надо подбирать на каком выводе будет нормально, также можно разные программы выставлять на разные схемы вывода.